# Text template custom host: how to implement ResolveDirectiveProcessor

Tags: c#, t4

Im trying to use this example from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb126579(v=vs.100).aspx) on how to create a custom host for text template generation.

The `CustomCmdLineHost` class implements the `ITextTemplatingEngineHost` interface but not completely, the `ResolveDirectiveProcessor` is not implemented and it throws each time an exception wich is normal. Here is the `ResolveDirectiveProcessor` method:

```
public Type ResolveDirectiveProcessor(string processorName)
    {
        //This host will not resolve any specific processors.
        //Check the processor name, and if it is the name of a processor the 
        //host wants to support, return the type of the processor.
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        if (string.Compare(processorName, "XYZ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
        {
            //return typeof();
        }
        //This can be customized to search specific paths for the file
        //or to search the GAC
        //If the directive processor cannot be found, throw an error.
        throw new Exception("Directive Processor not found");
    }
```

and `processorName` passsed to this function is "T4VSHost",

**The question now:**
What is the type of "T4VSHost" to return in this method ?

P.S.: i tried "Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.Directives.FallbackT4VSHostProcessor" but it seems that it doesnt exist in any namespace.

Comment: are you testing this straight from the command line like in the example?

Comment: @Frank  no it is called by some other code in the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the only way is to create that type. how ? by creating a class (lets call it `FallbackT4VSHostProcessor`) that inherits from the `DirectiveProcessor` abstract class which lives in the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating` namespace (the only example i found in the internet is [Here](https://github.com/mrward/entityframework-sharpdevelop/blob/master/src/EFTools/EntityDesign/VisualStudio/CustomDirectiveProcessor/FallbackT4VSHostProcessor.cs)). then we need to return the type of `FallbackT4VSHostProcessor` in the `ResolveDirectiveProcessor` like this:

```
Type ITextTemplatingEngineHost.ResolveDirectiveProcessor(string processorName)
    {
        if (string.Compare(processorName, "T4VSHost", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
        {
            return typeof(FallbackT4VSHostProcessor);
        }
        throw new Exception("Directive Processor not found");
    }
```

I hope this will help someone someday.